# Unable to get Control back to the flow after catch exception strategy

Tags: mule, mule-component

After catching and handling the exception using  catch exception strategy I am unable to bring back the control to the main flow in mule. Is there any way to continue the normal execution in mule like we have in java.
Please refer the code for more detais.

Simple web service class:

```
public class HorrorScopeService {

    public String getHorrorScopeByMonth(String month) throws Exception   {
        /*CustomLogger.info(CustomLogger.requestLogger, this.getClass(), "getHorrorScopeByMonth()", "PROCESSING REQUEST");
        CustomLogger.info(CustomLogger.requestLogger, this.getClass(), "getHorrorScopeByMonth()", String.format("MONTH FOR WHICH REQUEST IS PROCESSING IS  %s", month));*/
        //CustomException customException=null;
        CustomLogger.infoRequest(CustomLogger.requestLogger, "RID_9051844007", "REQUEST", "TESTING", "9051844007", "ha ha ha");
        String status="SUCCESS";
        System.out.println("1111111111111111111111");
        String data=null;;
        try{
        switch(month) {
        case "JAN":
            data="Not a good month to be born";
            break;
        case "FEB":
            data="People born in this month are ok ok";
            break;
        case "MAR":
            data="People born in this month are good";
            break;
        case "APR":
            data="People born in this month are brilliant";
            break;
        default:
            status="FAIL";
            data="you should not be born";
            int number=2;
            int result=number/0;
        }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("2222222222222222222222222222");
            throw new CustomException(e, "RID_905184", "9051844",
                    this.getClass(), "getHorrorScopeByMonth()");

        }   finally {
        CustomLogger.infoResponse(CustomLogger.requestLogger, "RID_9051844007", "RESPONSE", "TESTING", "9051844007", "90SEC", status, status,(String) data);
        CustomLogger.infoFunctionalKeyValueLog(CustomLogger.functionalLogger, "RID_9051844007", "ERROR", "TESTING",  "9051844007", this.getClass(), "getHorrorScopeByMonth()",(String) data);

        System.out.println("55555555555555555555555555555");
        }
        return data;

    }
}
```

Handler class: This is the class which handles the exception

```
import org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException;
import org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer;
import com.comviva.custom.exception.CustomException;
import com.comviva.custom.logger.CustomLogger;

public class CustomExceptionHandler extends AbstractTransformer{

    @Override
    protected Object doTransform(Object src, String enc)
            throws TransformerException {

        System.out.println("33333333333333333333333333 "+src.toString()+ " enc="+enc);
        CustomException exceptionClass=(CustomException)src;
        //System.out.println("print stack trace=");
        //exceptionClass.getEx().printStackTrace();

        System.out.println("4444444444444444444444get stack trace="+exceptionClass.getEx().getCause() );

        CustomLogger.error(CustomLogger.errorLogger, exceptionClass.getRequestId(), "ERROR", "TESTING", exceptionClass.getUserIdentifier(), exceptionClass.getClassName(),
                exceptionClass.getMethodName(),String.valueOf(exceptionClass.getEx().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber()), exceptionClass.getEx().getMessage(), exceptionClass.getEx());
        return src;
    }
}
```

After handling the exception i want finally block to execute but it is not getting executed. Is there any way to get the controller back to the thrower class after handling the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke the flow manually in the finally block

```
public class MyMessageProcessor implement MessageProcessor, MuleContextAware 
{ 
private MuleContext muleContext; 

public void setMuleContext(MuleContext context) 
{ 
this.muleContext = muleContext; 
} 

public MuleEvent process(MuleEvent event) 
{ 
Flow flow = (Flow)muleContext.getRegistry().lookupFlowConstruct("flowName"); 
//here you can mutate the payload, variables, properties, etc. before calling the flow 
return flow.process(event); 
} 
}
```

Comment: I will try this approach. But i think this will return the flow but when we call flow.process then it will process the flow from the beginning. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: If you want to handle exception at a particular component then try wrapping them in a transactional block and make them have their own exception strategy

Answer (score 0):

Found the work around for the problem:

Put the catch-exception processor in a seperate flow, and use a Flow Reference from your main flow to invoke that new flow. After the catch-exception triggers, execution after the Flow Reference is resumed.

For example;

```
<flow name="mainFlow">
     <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
     <flow-ref name="otherFlow" doc:name="otherFlow"/>
     <set-payload value="hello world" doc:name="Say hello"/>
 </flow>
 <flow name="otherFlow">
     <validation:is-true expression="#[false]" doc:name="throw exception"/>
     <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
         <set-payload value="exception occured" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
     </catch-exception-strategy>
 </flow>
```

mainFlow invokes otherFlow.

The validation-processor triggers an exception

The catch-exception-strategy runs

Execution resumes with set-payload "Say hello" in mainFlow

Notice that otherFlow is not a Sub Flow, as Sub Flows can not have their own exception strategy.